# How to prove the linear context free languages are closed under gsm mapping?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

I'm stuck on the following question:

**How to prove the linear context free languages are closed under gsm mapping?**

Comment: It would help us if you explained what linear (or linear context free) languages are, and what are gsm mappings.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What approaches have you tried?

Comment: While "linear" is a standard notion in formal languages (cc @YuvalFilmus), "GSM mappings" is even ungoogleable. What is that? Also, what @D.W. said.

Comment: @Raphael A *generalized sequential machine* is basically a transducer. It's an NFA with a string on each of the non-$\epsilon$ transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that gsm mappings can be written as a composition of an inverse morphism, intersection with a regular language, and a morphism, then it suffices to observe that the linear languages are actually closed under these operations.